# How to remove rows from ML.NET IDataView

Tags: c#, ml.net

I want to remove rows, from [IDataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.idataview?view=ml-dotnet), which satisfy some condition. Something similar to [DataOperationsCatalog.FilterRowsByMissingValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.dataoperationscatalog.filterrowsbymissingvalues?view=ml-dotnet), but working for more than just float numbers.

For example, I would like to remove rows where some of the columns are empty strings. How could we do that?

Comment: have you considered removing the data BEFORE loading it to ML.NET at all?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 That is a possibility, but it complicates things a bit. I cannot modify source data, so I would need to load it in memory, or copy it to another table with only filtered rows, and then load it into `IDataView`. Would prefer it through `IDataView` directly if possible